# How to add a transaction instruction to the beginning of a transaction?

Tags: transactions

I need to add an extra transaction instruction to an existing transaction. The instruction has to be added to the beginning of instructions lists.

The best approach I came up with is following:

```
const originalTransaction = transaction;
transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.add(extraInstruction);
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Transaction.add()` just concatenates the instruction to the `Transaction.instructions` array so you could just mutate that array yourself, if you like:

```
transaction.instructions.unshift(
  new TransactionInstruction({ <your instruction fields> }));
```